# What is the best way to update last row of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update last row of DataFrame.
But, what is the best way to update it?

I just want to update like following data.
Any suggestion?

```
time A B C
2019-01-01 1 2 3
2019-01-02 4 5 6
2019-01-03 7 8 9
```

↓

```
time A B C
2019-01-01 1 2 3
2019-01-02 4 5 6
2019-01-03 10 11 12
```

Comment: Data for update are in `list`? Or in `Series`? Or in another `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simpliest is assign list to last row with same number of values like number of columns:

```
df.iloc[-1] = [10,11,12]
print (df)
             A   B   C
time                  
2019-01-01   1   2   3
2019-01-02   4   5   6
2019-01-03  10  11  12
```

If want assign `Series` need index same like columns of updated `DataFrame`:

```
s = pd.Series([10,11,12])

s.index = df.columns
df.iloc[-1] = s
print (df)
             A   B   C
time                  
2019-01-01   1   2   3
2019-01-02   4   5   6
2019-01-03  10  11  12
```

Comment: I tried. But, I received this warning. What's wrong? SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: @naohide - I think need `copy` here, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986)

Comment: really, thank you :)